# Android processes Explanation references

Tags: android

Can somebody give me some useful links for explaining what each android process do. I can't seem to find any useful info. I'm making big presentation and I need more informations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from here [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) and go till the end of the list on the left.

Also, a littler more explanation on how android manages processes - http://www.howtogeek.com/161225/htg-explains-how-android-manages-processes/

Comment: how long it takes to become android developer. I mean to have sufficient knowledge to make some decent apps ? If you already know java, xml, and familiar with programming ? :)

Comment: @user2982390 If you already know java and xml then it wouldn't take much time. It's just that you need to get familiar with Android APIs and how to use them according to your needs. There are a lot of tutorials available which will help you.

Comment: Maybe this is off topic, but I'll ask here. What is "the best" resource to start with developing for Android ? Like low level explanations, to introduce you to the story :D

Comment: @user2982390 You can get started with video tutorials - http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6